# Joomla Articles Opening In Same Page

Tags: php, joomla, module

Im still fairly new to Joomla and PHP.

I have a page on a website http://smileisnc.co.uk/index.php/news and when you click on 'read more' it opens the article on the same page. I want the article to open in a new window when i click on read more...

This is the code i have in there at the moment:

```
    <?php if ($params->get('show_readmore')) :?>
                    <p class="mod-articles-category-readmore">
                    <a class="mod-articles-category-title <?php echo $item->active; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
                    <?php if ($item->params->get('access-view') == false) :
                        echo JText::_('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_REGISTER_TO_READ_MORE');
                    elseif ($readmore = $item->alternative_readmore) :
                        echo $readmore;
                        echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', $item->title, $params->get('readmore_limit'));
                            if ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) != 0) :
                                echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
                                endif;
                    elseif ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) == 0) :
                        echo JText::sprintf('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_READ_MORE_TITLE');
                    else :
                        echo JText::_('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_READ_MORE');
                        echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
                    endif; ?>
                    </a>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding `target="_blank"` to your readmore a link, see below:

```
    <?php if ($params->get('show_readmore')) :?>
                <p class="mod-articles-category-readmore">
                <a class="mod-articles-category-title <?php echo $item->active; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?> target="_blank">
                <?php if ($item->params->get('access-view') == false) :
                    echo JText::_('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_REGISTER_TO_READ_MORE');
                elseif ($readmore = $item->alternative_readmore) :
                    echo $readmore;
                    echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', $item->title, $params->get('readmore_limit'));
                        if ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) != 0) :
                            echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
                            endif;
                elseif ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) == 0) :
                    echo JText::sprintf('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_READ_MORE_TITLE');
                else :
                    echo JText::_('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_READ_MORE');
                    echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
                endif; ?>
                </a>
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Basically you need to do this, but in a layout override.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Article still pops up at the bottom of the archived articles list. Any other ideas?